# How to Avoid Table-Specific DB Errors to Stop All Data Flow in Kafka Connect JDBCSinkConnector?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We have a Kafka -> Kafka Connect -> PostgreSQL stack that continuously writes data from dozens of topics from Kafka to tables in PostgreSQL. My colleague is working on triggers, functions and views on PostgreSQL for our business logic. Sometimes we get DB errors related to development of those triggers, which returns them to JDBCSinkConnector tasks, and this causes Connector to fail and stop **all** data flow. So if there is an error on a single table, data flow to all tables are stopped. `errors.tolerance` is set to all, but those DB errors are not related to the data. I spawned multiple tasks, but they all failed one by one in 5-10 minutes when they tried to insert data to the table with the error. Is there a way around this so that a table with errors is ignored but the flow to other tables continues?

Comment: Use multiple connectors rather than multiple tables in one

Comment: Tried initalizing connector per table, but this caused high CPU load and had to reboot. I think Kafka Connect just doesn't have any support for DB error handling. See the end table of [related confluent blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/)